# Base64 BLOB Image Encode/Decode Express End Point INSERT MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, base64

I want to take a image from a form in html and encode to blob and insert into mysql database from and express endpoint.

I actually have :

```
app.use(fileUpload())
app.post('/uploadImage', function(req, res) {

 if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
    return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
  }

 var encoded = base64.encode(req.files.sampleFile.data);

 connection.query(

    'INSERT INTO ICONS (ID, LANGUAGE_ICON) VALUES   (1,"'+encoded+'")' ,
     //'INSERT INTO ICONS (ID,LANGUAGE_ICON) VALUES (1,'+JSON.stringify(encoded)+')' ,
function(err, response) {
    if(err){
        //console.log(err);
        console.log("ERROR!")
        res.json({ data: "ERROR" });
        res.end();
    }else{
        console.log("Correcto!")
        res.json({ data: encoded });
        res.end();
      }
            }
    );
```

That code **WORK PERFECT** , because i take the JSON response and checked in a base64 decode image page.

But when I want to DECODE in another endpoint returns a longblob but **NOT WORKING**

```
 router.get("/icons", function(req, res) {
    connection.query("select * from icons " , function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        if (result != "") {


            var respuesta = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                var base64String = base64.encode(result[i].LANGUAGE_ICON);
                respuesta[i] = base64String;
            }

            res.json({ iconos: respuesta });
        }
        else {
            res.json({ data: null });
        }
    });
  });
```

This last endpoint work perfectly when when I inserted the images via JS, like this:

```
var query2 = connection.query('create table icons (id int,LANGUAGE_ICON LONGBLOB)', function(err, result){
  console.log(result);

})

var A ={
  id:1,
  LANGUAGE_ICON: fs.readFileSync('./src/app/Blog/assets/es.png')  
}


var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO icons SET ?', A, function(err, result){
  if(err){
    console.log("te")
  }else{
    console.log(result);
  }

  })

A
```

Comment: You have this line in your decoding example. `var base64String = base64.encode(result[i].LANGUAGE_ICON);`  Should you, maybe, be trying to decode that result instead?

Comment: Yeah, that was the point. When I inserted it through JS, it didn't make an encode, it buffered directly.

Thank you